# Sidebar with 3 different backgrounds

Tags: html, css, xhtml, background-image

I'm currently trying to get my sidebar working with 3 different backgrounds. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igI9I.jpg)

I tried to fix it with 3 containers but I can't get it right (the top image disappears, etc). Any advice on the best way how to do this would be great.

[Demo](http://tinker.io/061dd)

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="block">
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
            Test<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
    background: url(http: //i.imgur.com/NNtfaL6.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    width: 190px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.head  {
    background: url(http: //i.imgur.com/sOVew68.png) top left no-repeat;
    width: 260px;
}
.block {
    background: #1b1b1b;
    color: #fff;
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have?

Comment: Show us the code and if you can,  an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @karancan http://jsfiddle.net/287Mt/ (I know my code is shit but I never really got in to CSS, PHP is more my thing).

Comment: i checked out your fiddle and could sometimes see the image and sometimes not. my best guess at this point is that it's something weird with imgur's servers. have you tried linking to an image on a different server? if my guess is right, that should solve it.

Comment: @maxedison that isn't the problem, when I've the images localhost it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @maxedison is right about the image not showing

Comment: @karancan is http://tinker.io/061dd working for you?

Comment: if you see your browser log, you will see: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://i.imgur.com/NNtfaL6.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://i.imgur.com/sOVew68.png

Comment: When running it on localhost, do you get any error about the image not being found? Maybe you aren't referencing their url correctly...

Comment: @Hidde the new link works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sliding door

Instead of using 2 small images and filling in the rest with a background color, it's much simpler to [make the top image taller than needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFqIY.png), and use the same small image at the bottom. Because the images are in PNG format, making the top image extremely tall adds very little to the size of the image (since the part that's being added is just a block of 2 different colors, which compresses very efficiently in PNG images).

This approach, using an image that's much larger than needed, is call a "sliding door". Usually, it's applied horizontally to style variable-width content, but it can be used vertically as well, as in this case, to style variable-height content.

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/unQKs/4/)   (if there's any trouble running it in JSFiddle, here's a [standalone version](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/unQKs/4/show) of the demo)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>
        Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>
        Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    /* Short bottom image */
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/q3Y9q16.png) 70px bottom no-repeat;
    width: 266px;
    padding-bottom: 36px;   /* Same as height of short bottom image */
}
.inner {
    /* Tall top image */
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFqIY.png) 0px top no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 74px 10px 20px 90px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're my new hero. I'll read some more info about sliding door techniques for in the future. Thanks again!